# Object not supported error in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hei');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="btn" />
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting an "object not supported" error on `$(document).ready`. I'm also getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: AFAICT, your code is correct. Is this your **exact** HTML? Or are you, for example, loading other JavaScript that might interfere with jQuery in the global namespace?

Comment: i'm also getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error in jquery file

Comment: Try [using jQuery from a CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) to ensure you have an unmodified version of jQuery.

Comment: i tried from CDN but this time when i tried debugging with firefox, it showed an error in /*! jQuery v1.7.2 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */ which is the header of http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct, it looks like jQuery file is not loaded, verify that it has correct path.

This works:

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                                  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() { alert('hi'); });
</script>                                                               
</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                  
</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

Comment: He probably means he had `ready` in the first place. `onready` would not result in not supported error or syntax error..

Comment: Right, then, it looks like jQuery is not loaded, so syntax error might be caused by `$`.

Comment: i'm also getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL error in jquery file